# Unable to set value to custom field Dynamics 365

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

**Background**

- I have created a custom field in Dynamics 365 named `new_statecode`.
- I am using an HTML webresource to get input from the user, that I later intend to pass to the custom field mentioned above.

  `<input id="statecode" type="text" placeholder="">`
- I have written a Java script to get the value entered by the user and set the value in the custom field.

This is the code for the script.

```
document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var strstatecode = document.getElementById("statecode").value;
    window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_statecode").setValue(strstatecode);
});
```

**The problem**

This is the error I am getting in the console.

```
Unable to get property 'setValue' of undefined or null reference
```

*I get a similar error when trying to use `getValue` property too.*

Apparently this is a very common issue but none of the other solutions work for me.

**What I have done so far**

- I have looked [here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/151256), [here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/137255), [here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/136792) and at tons of other posts.
- I have checked the custom field name. There is no typo or spelling mistake.
- I have tried using `window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_statecode").setValue(strstatecode);`
- I have tried creating a new custom field and tried to set the value to it. That did not work either. It gives the same error.

**Note1**:
I think it is worth mentioning that the code I have posted has been edited and shortened to match the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) standards of SO. There are 6 other inputs (Street address, City, etc.) in my HTML webresource and I am successfully able to save the data to their respective fields in CRM. The only difference is that those are not custom fields.

**Note2**: I am using Dynamics 365 Version 1612 (8.2.1.410).

How do I fix this problem? Is there anything else I should look at? Maybe something I should have paid attention to while creating that custom field?

Forgive my lack of knowledge in CRM jargon.

Comment: Are you including `<script src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript"></script>` in your web resource? Also, as a test, what happens if you assign the value to the custom field from a regular form JavaScript library rather than a web resource?

Comment: TBH I didn't. But now I have included it, hit save and then publish (am I doing this right?). Still no change. Same error

Comment: Yes, after updating it, save and publish will make it active. Of course you also have to refresh the browser too, and as an extra measure you can refresh without the cache in certain browsers using CTRL-F5, or empty the cache, then refresh.

Comment: Let me try that

Comment: @Aron Just an observation. I had noticed this before. The `<head>` tag fills with empty and `<meta>` and `<style`> tags. Is this normal behavior? Additionally, the `<script src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript"></script>` is no longer there. But I am sure I saved and published after making the changes.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen the system create those meta and style tags before. Strange that the script got taken out. Can you post a screenshot of your web resource configuration on the form, and of the form when it loads?

Comment: Is the field you have created on the form or not? You don't mention it.

Comment: @Aron It seems the changes I had made earlier somehow did not get saved. I have tried again and the script is still there. The error has not been resolved though. Again, I have to apologize for my lack of knowledge in CRM, but what screenshots are you asking for? Do you mean the HTML code?

Comment: @jcjr No. As of now they are not on the form. Is that a requirement for this to work?

Comment: You are a lifesaver @jcjr . Thanks a lot. I have been trying to solve this for the last few days. Please post that as the solution.

Comment: @Aron Thanks for the input about the `<script src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript"></script>`. @jcjr's comment solved it for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An attribute/field **needs to be present on a form** to be reachable by `Xrm.Page.getAttribute(attributeName)`.

However, it can be hidden, or placed in a hidden section or tab.